# Create Custom Web Components and share its in different framework

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, frontend, micro-frontend

I'm working on two projects developed by Angular and React.
Sometimes some components are the same in both projects and I'm thinking to create a company library to write a Custom Component only once and then deliver all the components to Angular and React.

After some research I understood that I have to create a Custom Component and then implement this component through all frameworks (Angular, React).

So the question is: Which is the best practice to create and organize a library repository to store all these components for different web frameworks? Which is the best practice to deliver this components?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the native [Web Components Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Web_Components), maybe use something like [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) for support.
In the end, Angular and React is just JS and you can use any other JS with it.
The implementations for each specific framework would either be implemented by the user or in diffrent packages depending on the original package.